# How to find last item in a repeated structure in bigquery

Tags: json, google-bigquery, jsonpath, nested-repeater

I have a nested repeated structure, the repeated structure is of variable length. For example, it could be a person object with a repeated structure that holds cities the person has lived in. I'd like to find the last item in that list say to find current city person lives in. Is there an easy way to do this, I tried looking around jsonpath functions but I'm not sure how to use it with "within". Any help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You can use [LAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference) and [WITHIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#within)

```
SELECT  
  FIRST(cell.value) within record ,
  LAST(cell.value) within record 
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
where ngram = "! ! That"
```

---

2) or if you want something more advanced you can use [POSITION](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#otherfunctions)

`POSITION(field)` - Returns the one-based, sequential position of field within a set of repeated fields.

You can check the samples from trigrams (click on Details to see the unflatten schema)
https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/publicdata:samples.trigrams?pli=1

[image]

And when you run POSITION, you get the ordering of that field.

```
SELECT  
  ngram,
  cell.value,
  position(cell.volume_count) as pos,
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
where ngram = "! ! That"
```

[image]

Now that you have the position, you can query for last one.

Comment: that's great - is it also possible to have the first item and last item in same SELECT clause?

Comment: yes you can have that, or you can use a subquery every time

Comment: Do you mean writing subquery for fetching first and another subquery to fetch last items?

Comment: @opensourcegeek if you would given a try you would figure it out by now, see my updates answer, it works in the same query.